# Swift рекурсивный обход картинки

Tags: swift, рекурсия, обработка-изображений

Нуждаюсь в совете.
Пытаюсь перенести класс разбивающий картинку на спрайты по маске с Lua на Swift.
Разбиваю картинку на регионы рекурсивным обходом. Сначала я пробовал работать напрямую с массивом пикселей, но такой код падал в  EXC_BAD_ACCESS примерно на 300 шаге. Поэтому я постарался максимально упросить задачу - я использую массив oPixels[x][y] в котором храниться значение цвета и номер региона. Такой код позволяет обойти небольшие картинки (до 200х200 пикселей) , но крашится на больших. Причем, исходник на Lua запускался на iPad в Codea и спокойно обрабатывал изображения 1024х768. 
Отсюда вопрос: есть ли какие то хитрости, которые необходимо использовать в Swift для рекурсивного обхода больших массивов?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
func ReadByColor(oColor:UIColor){
    var iRect = 1
    for x in 0...Int(pSize.x){
        for y in 0...Int(pSize.y){
            if(oPixels[x]![y]![1]==0){//Есди еще не использован
                if(oPixels[x]![y]![0]==0){//Есди не маска
                    RecurseFindByArray(x: x,y: y,iRect: iRect)
                    iRect = iRect + 1 //должен сработать после выхода из рекурсии 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func RecurseFindByArray(x:Int,y:Int,iRect:Int){
    self.iStack = self.iStack + 1
    if(self.iStack>=self.iStackMax){
        return
    }
    if(self.oPixels[x]![y]![0] != 0){
       return //Маска
    }
    if(self.oPixels[x]![y]![1] != 0){
        return
    }
    print("Вход в рекурсию ",self.iStack,x,y,":",self.oPixels[x]![y]![0],self.oPixels[x]![y]![1])
    if(self.oPixels[x]![y]![0] == 0){//Не маска
        if(self.oPixels[x]![y]![1] == 0){//Не обрабатывался ранее
            self.oPixels[x]![y]![1] = iRect;//EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16fc6bfd0)
            //print("Установили ",x,y,"=",self.oPixels[x]![y]![1])
        }
    }
    if(x>0){//Шаг влево
        self.RecurseFindByArray(x:x-1,y:y,iRect:iRect)

    }
    if(x<Int(self.pSize.x-1)){//Шаг вправо
        self.RecurseFindByArray(x:x+1,y:y,iRect:iRect)

    }
    if(y>0){//Шаг вниз
        self.RecurseFindByArray(x:x,y:y-1,iRect:iRect)
    }
    if(y<Int(self.pSize.y-1)){//Шаг вверх
        self.RecurseFindByArray(x:x,y:y+1,iRect:iRect)

    }
}
```